# Random "Could not load NIB in bundle" in UITableView

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a MonoTouch application that seems to throw an exception randomly on the device:

```
Jan 19 11:54:31 unknown UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.myapp[0xbab7][552] 
<Notice>: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  
Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: 
    Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/my-guid/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyTableCellController' Jan 19 11:54:31 unknown UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.myapp[0xbab7][552] <Notice>:   
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  Jan 19 11:54:31 unknown UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.myapp[0xbab7][552] <Notice>:  
at MyDataSource.GetCell (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  Jan 19 11:54:31 unknown UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.myapp[0xbab7][552] <Notice>:   
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  Jan 19 11:54:31 unknown UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.myapp[0xbab7][552] <Notice>:   
at MyApp.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What I have is a UIViewController with a XIB file laying out the UI.  The XIB sets up a custom UITableViewCell with other controls and outlets on it, etc.

Here is an example of the GetCell method throwing the error:

```
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            MyCellController controller = null;
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellName);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                controller = new MyCellController();
                cell = (UITableViewCell)controller.View;
                cell.Tag = _count++;
                _controllers[cell.Tag] = controller;
            }
            else
            {
                controller = _controllers[cell.Tag];    
            }
            controller.LoadStuff(_myArrayOfStuff[indexPath.Row]);   
            return cell;
        }
```

The error occurs on the line `cell = (UITableViewCell)controller.View`, and I'm assuming the error is something to do with the XIB not being loaded yet.

I've only gotten the crash to happen randomly on the device, and only when scrolling around quickly.

I've heard that XIBs are sometimes loaded asynchronously, my constructor for my UIViewController just looks like this:

```
public MyTableCellController () : base ("MyTableCellController", null)
{
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  It might be hard to make a repro for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the following error: you try to set your stuff before the view for your cell controller has been loaded. But I'm not very sure. :-)

Two different ways could be followed:

1) Load the xib synchronously like the following

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("YourNibName", this, null);
```

For further information see the following tutorial [monotouch-custom-tables](http://www.infoq.com/articles/monotouch-custom-tables).

2) Follow the following tutorial on [Creating-Custom-UITableViewCells-with-MonoTouch-the-correct-way](http://www.alexyork.net/blog/post/Creating-Custom-UITableViewCells-with-MonoTouch-the-correct-way.aspx)

In my opinion you could try to follow the second one, if this does not mean to change a lot of code. I like the second one because it reflexes the way you create custom cells in iOS. In iOS development when you create custom cells you don't create controller for cells. A cell is only a view where you put data. It's like a sort of placeholder that changes its content dynamically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm going to try #2 as I don't think I need a controller for each cell in my case.

Comment: After a second look, it is a memory issue.  My ReuseableIdentifier on each cell was not setup properly.  I'm going to take the time to redo these tables like your option #2 as well, thanks.

Comment: I understood your problem. Happy to hear that it works. Cheers.